# Loop to add to a string - servlet

Tags: html, servlets

So I'm currently working on a homework of ours that creates a histogram using asterisks. I created the int variables that counts the number of votes and string variables to hopefully loop '*' until it reaches the amount of votes.

```
String ast_a = "";
        String ast_b = "";
        String ast_c = "";
        String ast_d = "";
        String ast_e = "";
        int a = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("strong-dissatisfy"));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dissatisfy"));        
        int c = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("neutral"));
        int d = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("satisfy"));
        int e = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("strong-satisfy"));
```

However, I'm lost on how to add the asterisks together. 
`for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
{ ast_a = "*";}`
What can I do to add asterisks? Thanks!

Comment: could you help us with your desired output?

Comment: @BhavikPatel someone already answered my question but basically, I just want to print asterisks for every vote I get. Example, if I got 19 votes in satisfied, it will print 19 asterisks. I apologize for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ast_a = "*";`
With `ast_a += "*";`

Using the = operator will overwrite the value of ast_a on every loop. Using += will append to the value of ast_a  on each loop.